# How to represent trend over time?

Tags: raster, time, gis-principle

I have a time series of rasters where the cells of each raster represents some value at a certain time.

I would like to generate a map that highlights the magnitude of positive or negative trends in this value over time for each cell.

My somewhat naive approach is to fit a simple linear regression (X=time and Y=value) to each cell and output the array of slopes to a raster (as per example images below).  This can be filtered by only exporting significant results.

[image: time series from four individual cells]

[image: Slopes from linear regression]

How else might I represent trend over time in a raster timeseries?

I am interested in general techniques not software specific instructions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Plotting the estimated slopes, as in the question, is a great thing to do. Rather than filtering by significance, though--or in conjunction with it--why not map out some measure of how well each regression fits the data?  For this, the mean squared error of the regression is readily interpreted and meaningful.

As an example, the `R` code below generates a time series of 11 rasters, performs the regressions, and displays the results in three ways: on the bottom row, as separate grids of estimated slopes and mean squared errors; on the top row, as the *overlay* of those grids together with the true underlying slopes (which in practice you will never have, but is afforded by the computer simulation for comparison).  The overlay, because it uses color for one variable (estimated slope) and lightness for another (MSE), is not easy to interpret in this particular example, but together with the separate maps on the bottom row may be useful and interesting.

[image: Maps]

(Please ignore the overlapped legends on the overlay.  Note, too, that the color scheme for the "True slopes" map is not quite the same as that for the maps of estimated slopes: random error causes some of the estimated slopes to span a more extreme range than the true slopes.  This is a general phenomenon related to [regression toward the mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_toward_the_mean).)

BTW, this is not the most efficient way to do a large number of regressions for the same set of times: instead, [the projection matrix can be precomputed and applied to each "stack" of pixels](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/65841) more rapidly than recomputing it for each regression.  But that doesn't matter for this small illustration.

---

```r
# Specify the extent in space and time.
#
n.row <- 60; n.col <- 100; n.time <- 11
#
# Generate data.
#
set.seed(17)
sd.err <- outer(1:n.row, 1:n.col, function(x,y) 5 * ((1/2 - y/n.col)^2 + (1/2 - x/n.row)^2))
e <- array(rnorm(n.row * n.col * n.time, sd=sd.err), dim=c(n.row, n.col, n.time))
beta.1 <- outer(1:n.row, 1:n.col, function(x,y) sin((x/n.row)^2 - (y/n.col)^3)*5) / n.time
beta.0 <- outer(1:n.row, 1:n.col, function(x,y) atan2(y, n.col-x))
times <- 1:n.time
y <- array(outer(as.vector(beta.1), times) + as.vector(beta.0), 
       dim=c(n.row, n.col, n.time)) + e
#
# Perform the regressions.
#
regress <- function(y) {
  fit <- lm(y ~ times)
  return(c(fit$coeff[2], summary(fit)$sigma))
}
system.time(b <- apply(y, c(1,2), regress))
#
# Plot the results.
#
library(raster)
plot.raster <- function(x, ...) plot(raster(x, xmx=n.col, ymx=n.row), ...)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot.raster(b[1,,], main="Slopes with errors")
plot.raster(b[2,,], add=TRUE, alpha=.5, col=gray(255:0/256))
plot.raster(beta.1, main="True slopes")
plot.raster(b[1,,], main="Estimated slopes")
plot.raster(b[2,,], main="Mean squared errors", col=gray(255:0/256))
```

Answer (score 6):

There is an ArcGIS add-on developed by the USGS Upper Midwest Environmental Sciences Center called [Curve Fit: A Pixel Level Raster Regression Tool](http://www.umesc.usgs.gov/management/dss/curve_fit.html) that may be just what you are after.  From the documentation:

> Curve Fit is an extension to the GIS application ArcMap that allows
>   the user to run regression analysis on a series of raster datasets
>   (geo-referenced images). The user enters an array of values for an
>   explanatory variable (X). A raster dataset representing the
>   corresponding response variable (Y) is paired with each X value
>   entered by the user. Curve Fit then uses either linear or nonlinear
>   regression techniques (depending on user selection) to calculate a
>   unique mathematical model at each pixel of the input raster datasets.
>   Curve Fit outputs raster surfaces of parameter estimate, error, and
>   multi-model inference. Curve Fit is both an explanatory and predictive
>   tool that provides spatial modelers with the ability to perform key
>   statistical functions at the finest scale. Some examples of
>   hypothetical Curve Fit applications are: habitat variety as a function
>   of scale, population density as a function of time, or current
>   velocity as a function of discharge rate (see detailed example below).

Answer (score 5):

What you are describing is "Change Detection".  There are many techniques for change detection using rasters.  Probably the most common is image differencing where you subtract one image from another to produce a third.  Though, it depends upon the type of data you are trying to compare.  From your image, it looks like you're comparing changes in slope over time (unless this area is subject to major land works, this isn't likely to change much).  However, if you are comparing land class changes over time, you might use a different approach.

I came across [this article by D. Lu et al.](http://www.indiana.edu/~act/files/publications/2004/04-03_ChangeDetectionTechniques.pdf) in which they compare different methods of change detection.  Here's the abstract:

> Timely and accurate change detection of Earth’s surface features is
>   extremely important for understanding relationships and interactions
>   between human and natural phenomena in order to promote better
>   decision making. Remote sensing data are primary sources extensively
>   used for change detection in recent decades. Many change detection
>   techniques have been developed. This paper summarizes and reviews
>   these techniques. Previous literature has shown that image
>   differencing, principal component analysis and post-classiﬁcation
>   comparison are the most common methods used for change detection. In
>   recent years, spectral mixture analysis, artiﬁcial neural networks and
>   integration of geographical information system and remote sensing data
>   have become important techniques for change detection applications.
>   Different change detection algorithms have their own merits and no
>   single approach is optimal and applicable to all cases. In practice,
>   different algorithms are often compared to ﬁnd the best change
>   detection results for a speciﬁc application. Research of change
>   detection techniques is still an active topic and new techniques are
>   needed to effectively use the increasingly diverse and complex
>   remotely sensed data available or projected to be soon available from
>   satellite and airborne sensors. This paper is a comprehensive
>   exploration of all the major change detection approaches implemented
>   as found in the literature.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old question so, unlikely that the answer will be closed. However, I wanted to add some additional options to the previous answer and modernize the spatial classes. I have several timeseries related functions, applicable to rasters, in the spatialEco library (imputing missing values, smoothing, Mann-Kendall statistic, ..).

We can use the previous simulated example data.

```
library(terra)
library(spatialEco)
library(forecast)
set.seed(42)

dates <- date_seq("2001/01/01", "2002/12/31", "week")
n.row <- 100
n.col <- 100
n.time <- length(dates)

sd.err <- outer(1:n.row, 1:n.col, function(x,y) 5 * 
               ((1/2 - y/n.col)^2 + (1/2 - x/n.row)^2))
e <- array(rnorm(n.row * n.col * n.time, sd=sd.err), 
           dim=c(n.row, n.col, n.time))
beta.1 <- outer(1:n.row, 1:n.col, function(x,y) { sin((x/n.row)^2 - 
                (y/n.col)^3)*5} ) / n.time
beta.0 <- outer(1:n.row, 1:n.col, function(x,y) { atan2(y, n.col-x) } )
times <- 1:n.time
y <- rast(array(outer(as.vector(beta.1), times) + as.vector(beta.0), 
       dim=c(n.row, n.col, n.time)) + e)
```

We then want to fill in missing values (which is not relevant here but part of EDA of timeseries data) and smooth the timeseries to mitigate outlier effect while deriving the trend.

```
y.smooth <- app(y, impute.loess, smooth=TRUE)
```

Now we can start deriving trends (slope). First we calculate the nonparametric Mann-Kendall statistic (temporal correlation) with the monotonic Sen slope.

```
( k <- raster.kendall(y.smooth, tau = TRUE) )
```

Next, we apply a parametric method incorporating an Autoregressive AR(I) term. It is critical to address any periodicity in the data before applying these types of methods. This can be done by decomposing the data into the trend, seasonal and noise components and then extract the trend. We can write a function that can be passed to the terra app function that does both of these things (a step through is provided below).

```
# Detrend/slope function
ts.trend <- function(y, d=c(2001, 01), f = 52) {
  y <- na.omit(y)
  if(length(y) >= 12) { 
    detrend <- stats::decompose(stats::ts(y, start= c(2000, 01),
                                frequency = f))
      trend <- forecast::tslm(detrend$trend ~ trend)
      s <- stats::coefficients(trend)[2]
      se <- summary(trend)$sigma      
  } else {   
      s <- NA
      se <- NA    
  }
  return(c(as.numeric(s),as.numeric(se)))
}

# pass function to terra app and plot
slp <- app(y.smooth, ts.trend) 
  names(slp) <- c("slope", "std.err")
```

Now, plot Kendall and detrended slopes. Note that there are +/- 95% confidence interval and significance (p-value) rasters available for the Kendall statistic and standard errors for the parametric autoregression trend, we just are not plotting them.

```
dev.new(height=11, width=8)
  par(mfcol=c(2,1))
    plot(slp[[1]], main="detrended slope")
    plot(k[[1]], main="Kendall slope")
```

[image: raster slope's]

Here is a step through of what is going on at the pixel-level. We can extract the values of a single pixel and apply the above workflow.

Extract timeseries at cell number 1000.

```
x <- as.numeric(y[1000])
```

Smooth data with Loess regression and evaluate uncertainty using a Bootstrap. Some exploratory analysis helps hone in on an appropriate smoothing parameter. If you are simply filling in NA's (ie., smooth = FALSE) then you want a rather exact smoothing parameter such as s = 0.10. However, you do want to apply some smoothing so that outliers (eg., rare events) do not influence the underlying trend.

```
x.smooth <- impute.loess(x, s=0.02) 
sboot <- suppressWarnings(loess.boot(1:length(x), x, nreps=99, 
                       confidence=0.30, span=0.20))              
  dev.new(height=6, width=14)
    plot(sboot, main = "Loess smoothing with raw timeseries")
      lines(1:length(x), x, lty=3, col="blue")
        points(1:length(x), x, pch=20, cex=0.75, col="blue")
    legend("bottomleft", legend=c("smoothed (s=0.2)", "raw timeseires"),
           lty=c(2,3), pch=c(NA,20), col=c("black", "blue") )
```

[image: smoothed timeseries]

Here we derive the Kendall statistic

```
( k <- kendall(x.smooth) )
```

And, this breaks down the above function for decomposing and deriving an AR(I) trend

```
x.ts <- ts(x.smooth, start= c(2001, 01), frequency = 52)
  detrend <- decompose(x.ts)
    fit.dt <- forecast::tslm(detrend$trend ~ trend)
      trend.dt <- forecast(fit.dt, h=length(x), level=0)
        stats::coefficients(fit.dt)[2] # slope/trend
```

Note that the parametric slope is -0.0469 and the nonparametric slope on the smoothed data (not decomposed) is -0.04129 with a correlation (Tau) of -0.35348. So, there are times that the nonparametric statistic is more efficient. I will note that in certain cases the is something referred to as the long-run effect where, with very long timeseries (eg., n>500) can flatten out the slope making them very small in relation to the change. There are special statistics to help account for this (eg., long run mean and variance to help normalize the timeseries).